# On spiral shuffles

Tags: probability, card-games

I'm writting a program that shuffles the cards using a [Mexican spiral shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Mexican_spiral). In my case the number of unique cards is arbitrarily large but let's assume for the sake of simplicity that there are only 52 unique cards. The experiment is the following:

1. Given a deck of 52 cards shuffle them (`Collections.shuffle(cards)`) - this a Java shuffling library and it has nothing to do with the Mexican spiral shuffle, I just used this one so that my results can be more randomized. Let's assume that this randomized order of cards is the **original order**
2. After having a randomized list of cards start applying the Mexican spiral shuffle.
3. Keep applying the Mexican spiral shuffle until we reach the **original order** again. Once the hand deck is empty, take the table deck and repeat the shuffle. This designates one iteration of the shuffle.

I am making the following observation and I cannot really explain it. For a given number of cards the number of rounds required to reach the original order is fixed. For example, for a 52 card deck we need 510 rounds of a Mexical spiral shuffle to reach the original order. Irrespective of the order of cards in the original state. No matter how many times I run the simulation the results are the same.

To my understanding there are 52! permutations of the deck's state after the shuffle and I'm quite sure that we cannot reach all of them with the same probability. If this is the case how can the number of rounds for reaching the original order is always the same for a given number of cards?

Comment: The mexican spiral shuffle is deterministic. What it does is not dependent on the value of any card, only on its location. If I invented a new shuffle, and this shuffle simply reversed the order of a pack of cards, would you be surprised that regardless of what order the cards are in, just two rounds of my new shuffle will always put them back into their original order?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks for your response. What you're saying makes sense. Such a naive shuffling scheme (reverse the order of cards) we can be sure that after 2 shuffles the cards are going to be back in the original order. So there is a formula/method that produces the number of shuffles required. I'm trying to devise this formula for the mexican spiral shuffle. To my understanding it should only depend on the amount of cards in the deck

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I mean that since it's deterministic we can avoid all simulation to find the number of required shuffles to reach the original order right?

Comment: The Mexican Spiral shuffle is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of $52$ (or $n$) items. You can find the [order of the permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutation_order), the number of repetitions that make it do nothing, by taking the lowest common multiple of its cycle lengths.

Comment: The shuffle is somewhat complex, so I don't think there is a simple formula based on $n$. But you can just do the shuffle once on an ordered deck of $n$ cards, examine the result to find its cycles, and then calculate the order from that.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around your comment on cycle lengths

Comment: @JaapScherphuis So what you're suggesting is finding the lengths of ALL cycles of ALL permutations till I reach the initial order and then finding the least common multiple from all of these right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mexican Spiral shuffle is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of $52$ (or $n$) items. You can find the [order of the permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutation_order), the number of repetitions that make it do nothing, by taking the lowest common multiple of its cycle lengths.

The shuffle is somewhat complex, so I don't think there is a simple formula based on the number of cards $n$. But you can just do the shuffle once on an ordered deck of n cards, examine the result to find its cycles, and then calculate the order from that.

Here is an example. I'll use $9$ cards.

The cards start off as `ABCDEFGHI`, where `A` is the top card. A single mexican spiral shuffle affects the cards like this:

```
ABCDEFGHI
DFHB IGECA
FB HDIGECA
BFHDIGECA
```

So the end results is that card `A` went to the location of `I`, and card `I` went to the location of `E`, and so on. We get the following cycles:

`A`$\rightarrow$`I`$\rightarrow$`E`$\rightarrow$`G`$\rightarrow$`F`$\rightarrow$`B`$\rightarrow$`A`
`C`$\rightarrow$`H`$\rightarrow$`C`
`D`$\rightarrow$`D`

These cycles have lengths $6$, $2$, and $1$. The lowest common multiple of these lengths is $6$, so it takes $6$ shuffles for the cards to return to their original order.

If you do this with $52$ cards you'll find that the top card is part of a cycle of length $34$, the second card is in a cycle of length $10$, the fifth card is in a cycle of length $6$, and finally the 12th and 35th cards don't move (i.e. cycles of length $1$). The LCM of $34,10,6,1,1$ is $510$.